# ExecuteScalar requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed

Tags: c#, localdb, executescalar

When trying to register a new account in my program, via the LocalDB, I get an error stating:

ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed

But as you can see, I am opening the connection already

I have already tried setting the connection string in multiple places but to no avail

```
// The  methods which will be called if the user tries to log in or register
        private void LoginRegisterClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // The following lines of code will execute if the user tries to register
            if (lblView.Text == "Register")
            {
                // If all the textboxes have passed validation, the details from the textboxes are retrieved and stored
                if (ucRegister1.AllFieldsValidated() == true)
                {
                    string[] details = ucRegister1.ReturnRegisterDetails();
                    // (cmdCountUsernames) Checks to see if new username is unique
                    Helper.ConnectionToDB().Open();
                    SqlCommand cmdCU = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LoginsTable WHERE Login = '" + details[6] + "'", Helper.ConnectionToDB());
                    try
                    {
                        int count = (int)cmdCU.ExecuteScalar();
                        //int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmdCU.ExecuteScalar());
                        // If the new username is unique, the record is added into MainParentTable
                        if (count == 0)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                // Order of the details:         
                                // details[(0)Firstname, (1)Surname, (2)DOB, (3)HomeTel, (4)MobileTel, (5)Address, (6)Username, (7)Password, (8)Email]

                                // (cmdCNL) Creates a new record in the LoginsTable
                                SqlCommand cmdCNL = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO LoginsTable (Login, Password) VALUES (@login, @password)", Helper.ConnectionToDB());
                                Helper.ConnectionToDB().Open();
                                cmdCNL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", details[6]);
                                cmdCNL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", details[7]);
                                cmdCNL.ExecuteNonQuery();

                                // (cmdFindUserID) Finds the UserID of the new acccount which was just created above.
                                SqlCommand cmdFUID = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM LoginsTable WHERE Login = @login", Helper.ConnectionToDB());
                                cmdFUID.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", details[6]);
                                var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdFUID);
                                var dt = new DataTable();
                                da.Fill(dt);
                                globalVariables.userIDSelected = dt.Rows[0]["UserID"].ToString();

                                // (cmdInsertMainParentTable) Adds to the MainParentTable, a new parent using the UserID from the code above.
                                SqlCommand cmdIMPT = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO MainParentTable (UserID, FirstName, Surname, DOB, Address, HomeTelephone, MobileTelephone, Email) VALUES (@userid, @firstname, @surname, @dob, @address, @hometelephone, @mobiletelephone, @email)", globalVariables.conDB);
                                cmdIMPT.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", globalVariables.userIDSelected);
                                cmdIMPT.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", details[0]);
                                cmdIMPT.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", details[1]);
                                cmdIMPT.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", Convert.ToDateTime(details[2]));
                                cmdIMPT.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", details[5]);
                                cmdIMPT.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hometelephone", details[3]);
                                cmdIMPT.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobiletelephone", details[4]);
                                cmdIMPT.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", details[8]);
                                cmdIMPT.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                Helper.ConnectionToDB().Close();
                            }
                            catch (Exception msg2)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Error Message 2: " + msg2);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception msg)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error Message: " + msg);
                        throw;
                    }
                   // Helper.ConnectionToDB().Close();



                    // Populates and brings ucLogIn to the front of the form
                    ucLogIn1.PopulateLogins(details[6], details[7]);
                    lblView.Text = "Log In";
                    lblView.Location = new Point(293, 30);
                    ucLogIn1.BringToFront();                    
                }
                return;      
            }
```

Count should be set to either 0 or 1 based on the result of the query

---

GlobalVariables.Con simply does this

```
public static SqlConnection conDB = Helper.ConnectionToDB();
```

My helper class is as follows:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static SqlConnection ConnectionToDB()
    {
        return new SqlConnection (@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = G:\myDatabase.mdf; Integrated Security = True"); }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of `Helper.ConnectionToDB()`? And, unrelated but BTW, `AddWithValue()` is [evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: It fails on the line
                        int count = (int)cmdCU.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: GlobalVariables.Con simply does this ====> public static SqlConnection conDB = Helper.ConnectionToDB();


My helper class is as follows:

public static class Helper
    {
        public static SqlConnection ConnectionToDB()
        {
            
            return new SqlConnection (@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = G:\myDatabase.mdf; Integrated Security = True");

        }
    }

Comment: Connections should be created, used and disposed of in the smallest scope possible - typically a `using` block.  Same goes for COmmand and DataReader objects. That makes that helper more trouble than it is saves - the data all saved as string is another Big Red Flag.  Also,  passwords  should be salted and hashed before saving to the database

Comment: You should have [edit] your question to add the additional information not the comments. This time I did this for you. But the next time please remember and do it yourself.

Comment: Thank you @Stickybit
First time asking on StackOverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by this line (and similar lines in following commands)

```
SqlCommand cmdCU = new SqlCommand(........, Helper.ConnectionToDB());
```

I bet that your *Helper.ConnectionToDB* creates new instances of the SqlConnection object every time you call it.

Now, even if you have this line

```
  Helper.ConnectionToDB().Open();
```

You are opening a connection instance but, because the command calls again *Helper.ConnectionToDB*, you are getting a different instance in each command and using it while still closed.

You need a total different approach

```
.... previous stuff....
if (ucRegister1.AllFieldsValidated() == true)
{
    string[] details = ucRegister1.ReturnRegisterDetails();
    using(SqlConnection cnn = Helper.ConnectionToDB())
    {
        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmdCU = new SqlCommand("......", cnn);

        .... replace all calls to Helper.ConnectionDB with the cnn variable ....

        .....
    }  // <== This close the connection 
}
```

The [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) helps you here to keep under control your SqlConnection and the resources it uses. SqlConnection is a disposable object with important unmanaged resources linked to it. It is essential to free these resources as soon as possible and the using statement guarantees that when the code exits the using block the SqlConnection will be closed and disposed freeing the resources.

Comment: Thanks for this @Steve. I have followed this until line 8 of your instructions. When I add 'cnn' after the SQL statement on that line, it states an error "The name cnn does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Should not be possible. Review my code, the variable cnn is in context at the SqlCommand line. Check if there are some stray semi-colon that could change the scope